# Voice Recognition in Python

Tags: python-3.x, windows, voice-recognition

I'm currently working on a virtual assistant program in Python 3.3, and I'd like to incorporate voice recognition in it. Does anyone know of any python modules or tools to do this with? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Most of the solutions are not really portable. You forgot to mention OS you wanted to use. A good candidate is Pocketsphinx. For an example of a virtual assistant written in python you can check https://github.com/rob-mccann/Pi-Voice

Comment: Sorry. I'm running Windows 7 with Python 3.3. I'm checking into CMU Pocketsphinx.

Comment: Still can't find anything that works. I have tried Pocketsphinx and Dragonfly. Any other ideas?

Comment: If you have specific issues with pocketsphinx you are welcome to ask.

Comment: If anyone has anything other than Dragonfly or Pocketsphinx, please tell me.

Answer (score 3):

I've spent a lot of time working on this subject.

Currently I'm developing a Python 3 open-source cross-platform virtual assistant program called [Athena Voice](http://athena-voice.github.io/): https://github.com/athena-voice/athena-voice-client

Users can use it much like Siri, Cortana, or Amazon Echo.

It also uses a very simple "module" system where users can easily write their own modules to enhance it's functionality. Let me know if that could be of use.

Otherwise, I recommend looking into Google's Python speech-to-text and text-to-speech packages.

Both packages can be installed by using the command:

`pip install SpeechRecognition gTTS`

Google STT:
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/SpeechRecognition/

Google TTS:
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/gTTS/1.0.2

I believe the STT has PyAudio as a dependency which can be found here (unofficial):
http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio

However, if you intend to do passive/offline listening, I highly recommend reconsidering pocketsphinx. On Python 3.4 it can be installed just by typing "pip install pocketsphinx"

Comment: Is there any other alternative for offline STT @Connor instead of pocketsphinx.